# Can a function lock a mutex?

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, mutex

I'm writing a memory manager for a linux kernel that shares a cyclic list of PIDs between threads (project for school).
This program finds zombies and kills them using a 1 producer, 2 consumer model. (forced on us so that we can understand shared memory).

I would like to make this list an object and have functions deal with iterating the pointers and checking the values of the cells.

So, if a thread calls an external function, can the said function own the mutex? or does that have to be done from within the thread?

Am I thinking of this completely wrong?

Much thanks
-Jared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to say that a 'function' owns the mutex doesn't quite make sense. It is the thread that owns it. So yes, it is possible, whatever thread called your external function would own the mutex.

if you look in your kernal code for the implementation of threads, you'll see that one of its variables is a list of mutexes it owns.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to multi-threading, so I didn't quite know how to word it. I just wanted to make sure that the kernel wouldn't get confused by a mutex lock being inside of an external function.

Comment: One last thing: Do I need to pass the mutex as a parameter? I am declaring these functions in a header file.